# Problems with plotting of graphs

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub plottinggraphs()
Dim rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, rng5, rng6, rng7, rng8 As Range
Dim combine1 As Range
Dim combine2 As Range
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
Set rng1 = Range("L2:L" & LastRow)  'TTemp
Set rng2 = Range("B2:B" & LastRow)  'Time
Set rng3 = Range("N2:N" & LastRow)  'Current
Set rng3 = Range("M2:M" & LastRow)  'DCurrent
Set rng5 = Range("G2:G" & LastRow)  'HTemp
Set rng6 = Range("F2:F" & LastRow)  'LTemp
Set rng7 = Range("AT2:AT" & LastRow)  'RTemp
Set rng8 = Range("D2:D" & LastRow)    'VTemp
Set combine1 =Union(rng3,4,5,6,7,8)
Set combine2=Union(rng1,rng2)

With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
  .ChartType=xlXYScatterSmooth
  .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Graph"
      With .SeriesCollection(1)
         .XValues=ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
         ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=combine1
      End With

      With .SeriesCollection(2)
         .XValues=ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
         ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=combine2
      End With
End With 
End Sub
```

I have trouble plotting the graphs. I need to plot 2 graphs from another sheet called "Graph".
For the first graph, I need to plot DCuurent with Time which I have set as combine1. For the second graph, I need to plot TTemp, Current, DCurrent, HTemp, RTemp, RTemp, and VTemp with time.
However, both graphs cant come out.

Comment: At the first glance: `Dim rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, rng5, rng6, rng7, rng8 As Range` declares `As Range` only `rng8`. The rest are `Variant` type. Then `Set combine1 =Union(rng3,4,5,6,7,8)` is something at least strange. Only ranges can be combined. If you imagine that VBA should guess that you intent to refer to rng4, rng5 etc., this is never happening...

Comment: what do u think i should do then? i cant figure out a way to place all the ranges to plot the graph

Comment: Firstly to learn VBA, in terms of variable declaration, function parameters and then try. I do not think that a discontinue range, as you try building, will work, but I am not sure. Try manually inserting a chart selecting such a range and see what happens. If you want to add multiple series, this is another approach and it should work. But you must learn. There are plenty of examples of charts series adding in this community. Please, search try and learn. If you have a problem with a piece of code proving that you documented as it should, place a question here.

Comment: i got a solution that seems far-fetch and was pushing my luck over here. The database i have, have over 50 columns, is it possible to delete those columns that i don't need?

Comment: this leads to another pickle. Majority of the columns have values, how do i declare/manipulate the database to delete it

Comment: Searching, reading, trying and learning. You do  not know elementary issues...